# Searching from array (complex criteria) without unnesting?

Tags: postgresql

I have table with arrays of dates. How to search in them?

```
create table if not exists somedates (
startdate date,
otherdates date[]);

insert into somedates (startdate, otherdates) values
('2000-11-14', '{2001-10-30}'),
('2001-09-26', '{2002-09-20,2004-09-21,2006-09-19,2010-09-17}'),
('2005-05-10', '{2006-08-03,2008-08-12}'),
('2004-09-29', '{2005-09-29,2006-10-02,2007-10-04,2009-09-22,2010-08-06,2011-09-01,2013-09-17}');
```

I would want to find all rows, where in otherdates there is "1 year" (0.6 – 1.4) AND "5 year" (3.5 – 5.5) followup-dates found.

Following doesn't work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM somedates
WHERE any(otherdates) - startdate > 0.6*365
      and any(otherdates) - startdate < 1.4*365
      and any(otherdates) - startdate > 3.5*365
      and any(otherdates) - startdate < 5.5*365
;
```

Following works, but if there is (and there is in the real case) lots of dates, I should put lots more OR-cases.

```
select * from
    (SELECT *, generate_subscripts(otherdates, 1) as s
    FROM somedates) as foo 
where (otherdates[s] - startdate) >= 0.6*365
    and (otherdates[s] - startdate) <= 1.4*365
    and (
           ((otherdates[s+1] - startdate) >= 3.5*365
           and (otherdates[s+1] - startdate) <= 5.5*365)
        or ((otherdates[s+2] - startdate) >= 3.5*365
           and (otherdates[s+2] - startdate) <= 5.5*365)
        or ((otherdates[s+3] - startdate) >= 3.5*365
           and (otherdates[s+3] - startdate) <= 5.5*365))        
;
```

```
2001-09-26   {'2002-09-20','2004-09-21','2006-09-19','2010-09-17'}   1
2004-09-29   {'2005-09-29','2006-10-02','2007-10-04','2009-09-22','2010-08-06','2011-09-01','2013-09-17'}   1
```

Using some kind of ANY-structure somehow would make more sense than needing to enumerate all indexes.

I know by **unnesting** I can do the search also, but surely there should be a way to do this without unnesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the syntax were valid, your first query wouldn't do what you describe anyway, as you need to ensure it is same date from the array which is > one thing and < another thing, not two different dates.  You need to use ranges, both to be syntactically valid, and to be semantically valid.

```
select * from somedates where 
    daterange((startdate+interval'0.6 years')::date,(startdate+interval'1.4 years')::date) @> ANY (otherdates) and
    daterange((startdate+interval'3.5 years')::date,(startdate+interval'5.5 years')::date) @> ANY (otherdates);
```

You can make it a bit less ugly like this:

```
create or replace function daterange2(date, interval, interval) returns daterange 
  as $$ select daterange(($1+$2)::date, ($1+$3)::date) $$
  language sql immutable parallel safe;

select * from somedates where                                                                                             
    daterange2(startdate,'0.6 years','1.4 years') @> ANY (otherdates) and
    daterange2(startdate,'3.5 years','5.5 years') @> ANY (otherdates);
```